# return true or false if text contains certain text

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to return true or false on a excel spreadsheet where I have an email address in one cell and want to check if part of that adress contains certain text and return the value in the cell next to it. - is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to knock something together using IF and FIND.

```
=IF(FIND(find_text,within_text)>0,"true","false")
```

If you need it to be case insensitive simply change everything to upper or lower case first

```
=IF(FIND(UPPER(find_text),UPPER(within_text))>0,"true","false")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm still struggling here sorry.

Comment: example       abcdef@123456.com      if I wanted to return something if it contained 3456 and the email is in cell A1 how would you write that up? thanks again

Comment: How are you struggling? If you replace find_text with the text (in double quotes) or a reference to a cell you want to find and within_text with the email address, it will return true if it's found.

Comment: =IF(FIND(UPPER("3456"),UPPER(A1))>0,"true","false")

Comment: Thank you all, much appreciated, understand now and works cheers